# Return last inserted ID sqlalchemy sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to get the last inserted row id from an sqlalchemy insert with sqlite. It appears this should be easy but I haven't managed to figure it out yet and didn't find anything in my searches so far. I'm a new to python and I know there are some similar posts so I hope this is not a repeat. Below is some simple sample script:

```
from sqlalchemy import *    
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///myTest.db',echo=False)
metadata = MetaData()

dbTable1 = Table('dbTable1', metadata,Column('ThisNum', Integer),Column('ThisString', String))
metadata.create_all(engine)
dbConn = engine.connect()

insertList={}
insertList['ThisNum']=1
insertList['ThisString']='test'
insertStatement = dbTable1.insert().values(insertList)
lastInsertID = dbConn.execute(insertStatement).inserted_primary_key
```

The value returned is empty. I get the same result using

```
lastInsertID = dbConn.execute(insertStatement).last_inserted_ids()
```

I can get the last rowid using a separate statement after the insert:

```
lastInsertID = dbConn.execute('SELECT last_insert_rowid();')
```

But this would not guarantee the database had not been accessed in between the executions so the returned ID might not be correct. Lastly I tried executing the insert and select statements in one execution for instance:

```
lastInsertID = dbConn.execute('INSERT INTO "dbTable1" ("ThisNum", "ThisString") VALUES (1, "test"); SELECT last_insert_rowid();')
```

But this gives the error: sqlite3.Warning: You can only execute one statement at a time.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I can't believe I saw the problem right after posting. Should have thought for a couple minutes more. I missed that the primary key is not automatically assigned to ROWID if no primary key is identified. Just needed to add a primary key to the table. Then the primary key will autoincrement and the first execute statement gives the primary key back.

Comment: You should put that as an answer and mark it as accepted.